# Grounding score for RAG on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Using Azure, I was wondering if I can get the grounding score for the generated answer when using the RAG system through some API?

I see that it is possible to get the groundedness score for a certain dataset through the online console:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-studio/how-to/evaluate-generative-ai-app?pivots=ai-studio

But, that is not a viable approach for an online service where I want to check the groundedness score before passing the generated answer to the user.